# Send a proportional amount of ETH to every token holder

Tags: erc-20

I am creating a token, of which I can mint an unlimited amount. I will sell them to people.

Then I need to send another token, or ETH, to every holder of my token.
The amount sent should be proportional to the amount of token they hold.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should avoid loops in essential smart contract code because they will end up costing more and more gas the more token holders there are.

Therefore I would recommend a pattern somewhat like this:

```
mapping(address => uint256) public withdrawableETH;
mapping(address => uint256) public lastUpdateTotalETHdistributedPerToken;
uint256 public totalETHdistributedPerToken;

function updateTokenHolderWithdrawableETH(address _tokenHolder) public
{
     uint256 tokens = balanceOf(_tokenHolder);
     uint256 newETHperToken = totalETHdistributedPerToken - lastUpdateTotalETHdistributedPerToken[_tokenHolder];
     if (newETHperToken > 0)
     {
         withdrawableETH[_tokenHolder] += tokens * newETHperToken / (1 ether);
     }
     lastUpdateTotalETHdistributedPerToken[_tokenHolder] = totalETHdistributedPerToken;
}

function distributeETH() external onlyOwner payable
{
    totalETHdistributedPerToken += msg.value * (1 ether) / totalSupply;
}

function withdrawETH() external
{
     updateTokenHolderWithdrawableETH(msg.sender);
     uint256 amount = withdrawableETH[msg.sender];
     withdrawableETH[msg.sender] = 0;
     msg.sender.transfer(amount);
}
```

`updateTokenHolderWithdrawableETH(addr)` should be executed before every change in the balance of `addr`.

Token holders can call `withdrawETH()` to fetch their part of the ETH distributions that have happened since their last withdrawal.

If you really want to 'push' the ETH to the token holders, you could add a batch withdrawal function.